# Highlight return word and the return type in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, color-scheme

After manually changing the colors after selecting the blue theme, i noticed the following undesired highlights on the word "return" and the return type.
My cursor is currently on the word return. I have resharper installed.

How can i pinpoint which setting to change in colors.?

[image: code]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same issue and was able to fix it by disabling a setting in the Resharper options. Go to Resharper>Options and then under Code Inspection>Settings uncheck the "Highlight context exits" option.

Comment: Thanks, you. maerking as answered